# Hint is shifting from center when I add icon to edittext? How can align?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have a hint text in center.I add an icon to edittext with android:drawableLeft. When I add like this, hint text is not aligned to the center. It is shifting.Do you have any idea ?[image]

Comment: Add screenshot to better understand the issue.

Comment: Could you please share a required code snippet?

Comment: I shared @RajenRaiyarela

Comment: Please add the code of your layout, so we can present proposals based on your current code.

Comment: android:gravity="center"

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are seeing is proper. If you want the Text to be always in the center, you can add a FrameLayout and in that add your image and textview separately.
Inside your FrameLayout first, add text view with gravity center and then your image with gravity start.